Python Selenium - TimeOutException even with EC wait until clickable
I've attached a couple of screenshots and code snippets for reference:
BOOK test Shadow Root Code Snippet
url_test = "https://books-pwakit.appspot.com/"
driver.get(url_test)

shadow_host1 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "book-app[apptitle='BOOKS']")
shadow_root1 = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', shadow_host1)

print(shadow_root1)

shadow_host2 = shadow_root1.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "app-header[effects='waterfall']")
shadow_root2 = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', shadow_host2)

shadow_host3 = shadow_root1.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.toolbar-top')
shadow_root3 = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', shadow_host3)

shadow_host4 = shadow_root1.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.toolbar-bottom')
shadow_root4 = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', shadow_host4)

shadow_host5 = shadow_root1.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'book-input-decorator')
shadow_root5 = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', shadow_host5)

shadow_content = shadow_host5.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#input')
shadow_content.send_keys("1984")

Target website Shadow Root Code Snippet
# Wait for the images to load
img = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='cell8_4656663']/img"))
)

img.click()  # Click the PDF image

document_window = driver.window_handles[1]  # Switch to the new window
driver.switch_to.window(document_window)

print(driver.page_source)  # Print the HTML to see if the element is there

shadow_host1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "viewer"))
)
shadow_root1 = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', shadow_host1)

BOOK website HTML
BOOK
Target website HTML
TARGET
TimeOutException Error
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7A455B095+29557]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A44CFA50]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A438B56A]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A43DF695]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A43DF8EC]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A442B777]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A44071CF]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A442851C]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A4406F33]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A43D116F]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A43D22D1]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7A488C96D+3378253]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7A48D8497+3688311]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7A48CD1CB+3642539]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7A461A6B6+813462]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A44DAB5F]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A44D6B74]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A44D6D10]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7A44C5C1F]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FF8119B257D+29]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF81262AF28+40]

I am trying to access a shadow root  in order to press it to download a pdf embedded in the web page. However, I always face a TimeoutException even after setting a long EC wait for clickable action. I have tested the same shadow root method on another website taken from another answer ([BOOK]https://books-pwakit.appspot.com/), and the shadow root is perfectly accessible. I am not sure if the issue is with the :host([hidden]) style on the target website HTML?
